# Возможно ли доопределить поле класса, не меняя сам класс?

Tags: c#, классы

Здравствуйте. Решаю учебную задачу и никак не могу придумать, как сделать так, чтобы у геометрического класса Segment (с чисто геометрическими методами: длина, принадлежит ли вектор сегменту, с полями Begin и End типа Vector) хранилось свойство Color. Чтобы можно было расширить класс методами GetColor(Color color) и SetColor(Color color), при этом не изменяя сам класс Segment(или Vector).

```
public static class SegmentExtensions
{
    public static void SetColor(this Segment segment, Color clr)
    {

        segment.color = clr; // Это работает, только если добавить в класс
        // Segment поле Color.
    } 

    public static Color GetColor(this Segment segment)
    {
        return segment.color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Сама задача и состоит в том, чтобы придумать способ хранения информации о цвете отрезка (положим, мы не имеем доступа к базовому классу и хотим написать расширение). И по идее задача решается без наследования вообще. Возможно прозвучит глупо, но Segment и Vector - разные классы, наследования никакого нет.

Comment: паттерн декоратор? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Похоже на то, что нужно. Спасибо, буду разбираться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте класс-декоратор, который добавит нужные свойства вашим объектам. Если есть возможность использовать `Generics`, то можно сделать например так:

```
//в спецификаторе дженерика задаем, например, базовый тип всех геометрических объектов,
//которые собираемся раскрасить
class ColoredGeometryObject<T> where T : GeometryObject
{
    //Свойство для доступа к декорируемому объекту, только для чтения
    public T BaseObject { get; }

    //Добавленное свойство
    public int Color { get; set; }

    //Параметризованный конструктор декоратора
    public ColoredGeometryObject(T objectForDecoration)
    {
        BaseObject = objectForDecoration;
    }
}
```

Не самый каноничный пример, но как иллюстрация вполне подойдет.

Вообще на эту тему много материалов в интернете: [**Metanit**](http://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/4.1.php), [**Wiki**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), первые и далеко не единственные ссылки в выдаче Google.